# In a REST API, to GET a resource, should I include the resource ID in the url?

Tags: rest, http, get

I am trying to create an REST API for creating and retrieving files in my database. The tutorial I was following uses the following method to retrive a single file:

```
$app->get('/file/:file_id', 'authenticate', function($file_id) {
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // fetch file
        $result = $db->getFile($file_id, $user_id);

        if ($result != NULL) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["id"] = $result["id"];
            $response["file"] = $result["fileLocation"];
            $response["status"] = $result["status"];
            $response["createdAt"] = $result["created_at"];
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exist";
            echoRespnse(404, $response);
        }
    });
```

Here they are using the HTTP GET method and are specifying the file ID in the URL, is it OK to do this, safety wise? Would it not be safer to use POST and hide the file ID in the body of the request, or should they not be putting the file ID in a header with the GET request? or is it not something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In REST post method is used to create a new resource not to get it. Get method is used for fetching the resource and you need to specify the ID to determine particular resource. Passing it via URL is a common practice. You can randomly generate such ID to make it harder to guess.

Answer (score 1):

As Opal said above, the ID is used to identify a resource. If you are unsure have a read of this - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post